# Getting the temperature or pressure on the A17-Realtag-BLE-Sensor-Wearable

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

From this following sensor:
http://www.banggood.com/A17-Realtag-BLE-Sensor-Wearable-CC2541-MPU6050-BMP180-iBeacon-p-954754.html

How do you get the temperature from the sensor using Android via bluetooth on its advertisement data?

Answer (score 1):

In the advertisement data, look for parameters 0xFFA0 -> 0xFFB6 and 0xFFA0 -> 0xFFB7 which contain raw sensor data for MPU6050 and BMP180 respectively. Temperature data can be extracted from any of those values. Refer this [link](http://www.addta.com/resources/RealTag%20iBeacon_Sensor%20product%20guide.pdf) for details.